# Not able to listen to RabbitMQ message

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

In my project I am hitting API service and expecting message via RabbitMQ.
 I am using behave framework of Python for testing purpose.
 I am connecting a RabbitMQ. Creating queue, binding queue with exchange.

```
import pika
import logging

#logging.basicConfig(logging.INFO)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

#binding_keys = "TestTopic"
#_queue_name = None
#channel = None
class Rabbitmq(object):
    EXCHANGE_TYPE = "topic"
    BINDING_KEYS = "TestTopic"
    queue_state=None
    queue_empty=None
    queue_name=None

    def create_connection(test):
        logging.info("Started create_connection method")
        global queue_empty, queue_state,queue_name
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials("USERNAME", "USERNAME")
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host="HOST", port=PORT, credentials=credentials,virtual_host="virtual host")

        # establish connection
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
        global channel

        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.confirm_delivery()

        # declare exchange
        channel.exchange_declare(exchange="EXCHANGE_NAME",exchange_type="topic",durable=True)

        #declare queue
        result = channel.queue_declare(queue='QUEUE_NAME')

        queue_name = result.method.queue

        channel.queue_bind(exchange="EXCHANGE_NAME",
                               queue="QUEUE_NAME",
                               routing_key=Rabbitmq.BINDING_KEYS)
        logging.info("Ending create_connection method")


    def getMessage(self):
        logging.info("Starting getMessage")
        global channel,queue_state,queue_empty,queue_name

        logging.info("before callback method")


        def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
            print("listening [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))
            logging.info(" [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))


        channel.basic_consume(callback,queue="test_result_pdp_queue")
        logging.info("After basic_consume method")
        #logging.info(channel)
        channel.start_consuming()
        logging.info("After start_consuming")
```

Before starting my test execution I am calling create_connection method which will establish connection, declare exchange & queue.
Then I am hitting the API service and expecting a message via RabbitMQ where I am calling consume function for consuming message. But I am not getting any message. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you publish your message do you see it in the queue (you can use https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html to visualize)? Do you push the message using the correct routing key since your channel/queue are bind using your variable binding_key?

Comment: Apparently, I was not binding queue to exchange properly, hence when I was listening on this queue, I was not receiving any message. It got resolved now. Thanks @olibiaz .